# Links, Hyperlinks into a canvas using PDF.js

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, pdf.js

I'm using the PDF.js library to render a pdf into the canvas. That pdf has hyperlinks in there, The PDF.js library is drawing the pdf into the canvas but the hyperlinks don't work.

Any Idea if it possible that hyperlinks work into the canvas?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/seikichi/RuDvz/2/) is a fiddle that shows you how to enable annotations (including hyperlinks) in PDF files.
The original PDF file used in the fiddle is [here](http://seikichi.github.io/tmp/PDFJS.0.8.715/sample.pdf).

I used viewer code ([web/page_view.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/page_view.js),[web/viewer.css](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/viewer.css)) as refrence to write this fiddle.

**HTML:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://seikichi.github.io/tmp/PDFJS.0.8.715/pdf.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://seikichi.github.io/tmp/PDFJS.0.8.715/ui_utils.js"></script>
    <script src="./main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="pdfContainer" class="pdf-content">
      <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
      <div class="annotationLayer"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```css
body {
    font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}
.pdf-content {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.annotationLayer > a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
.annotationLayer > a:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
    background: #ff0;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #ff0;
}
.annotText > div {
    z-index: 200;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0.6em;
    max-width: 20em;
    background-color: #FFFF99;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #333;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.annotText > img {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.annotText > img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.annotText > div > h1 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
PDFJS.workerSrc = 'http://seikichi.github.io/tmp/PDFJS.0.8.715/pdf.min.worker.js';

$(function () {
  var pdfData = loadPDFData();

  PDFJS.getDocument(pdfData).then(function (pdf) {
    return pdf.getPage(1);
  }).then(function (page) {
    var scale = 1;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
    var $canvas = $('#the-canvas');
    var canvas = $canvas.get(0);
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    var $pdfContainer = $("#pdfContainer");
    $pdfContainer.css("height", canvas.height + "px")
      .css("width", canvas.width + "px");

    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    page.render(renderContext);
    setupAnnotations(page, viewport, canvas, $('.annotationLayer'));
  });

  function setupAnnotations(page, viewport, canvas, $annotationLayerDiv) {
    var canvasOffset = $(canvas).offset();
    var promise = page.getAnnotations().then(function (annotationsData) {
      viewport = viewport.clone({
        dontFlip: true
      });

      for (var i = 0; i < annotationsData.length; i++) {
        var data = annotationsData[i];
        var annotation = PDFJS.Annotation.fromData(data);
        if (!annotation || !annotation.hasHtml()) {
          continue;
        }

        var element = annotation.getHtmlElement(page.commonObjs);
        data = annotation.getData();
        var rect = data.rect;
        var view = page.view;
        rect = PDFJS.Util.normalizeRect([
          rect[0],
          view[3] - rect[1] + view[1],
          rect[2],
          view[3] - rect[3] + view[1]]);
        element.style.left = (canvasOffset.left + rect[0]) + 'px';
        element.style.top = (canvasOffset.top + rect[1]) + 'px';
        element.style.position = 'absolute';

        var transform = viewport.transform;
        var transformStr = 'matrix(' + transform.join(',') + ')';
        CustomStyle.setProp('transform', element, transformStr);
        var transformOriginStr = -rect[0] + 'px ' + -rect[1] + 'px';
        CustomStyle.setProp('transformOrigin', element, transformOriginStr);

        if (data.subtype === 'Link' && !data.url) {
          // In this example,  I do not handle the `Link` annotations without url.
          // If you want to handle those annotations, see `web/page_view.js`.
          continue;
        }
        $annotationLayerDiv.append(element);
      }
    });
    return promise;
  }
});

function loadPDFData() {
  /*jshint multistr: true */
  var base64pdfData = '...'; //should contain base64 representing the PDF

  function base64ToUint8Array(base64) {
    var raw = atob(base64);
    var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(raw.length));
    for (var i = 0, len = raw.length; i < len; ++i) {
      uint8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return uint8Array;
  }
  return base64ToUint8Array(base64pdfData);
}
```

Comment: shared resources and fiddle are not working.. can you update the content

Answer (score 0):

## Enable Text Selection in PDF.JS

---

### Step 1: Adding a  Element to Hold the Text Layer

```html
<div id="text-layer"></div>
```

This div will be in addition to the  element where the PDF is rendered, so the HTML will look like :

```html
<canvas id="pdf-canvas"></canvas>
<div id="text-layer"></div>
```

### Step 2 : Adding CSS for Text Layer

Add the following to your CSS file :

```css
#text-layer { 
   position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.2;
    line-height: 1.0;
}

#text-layer > div {
    color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: pre;
    cursor: text;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

### Step 3: Getting the PDF Text

After the PDF has been rendered in the canvas, you need to get the text contents of the PDF, and place that text in the text layer.

```js
// page is the page context of the PDF page
// viewport is the viewport required in renderContext
// For more see https://usefulangle.com/post/20/pdfjs-tutorial-1-preview-pdf-during-upload-wih-next-prev-buttons    

page.render(renderContext).then(function() {
    // Returns a promise, on resolving it will return text contents of the page
    return page.getTextContent();
}).then(function(textContent) {
     // PDF canvas
    var pdf_canvas = $("#pdf-canvas"); 

    // Canvas offset
    var canvas_offset = pdf_canvas.offset();

    // Canvas height
    var canvas_height = pdf_canvas.get(0).height;

    // Canvas width
    var canvas_width = pdf_canvas.get(0).width;

    // Assign CSS to the text-layer element
    $("#text-layer").css({ left: canvas_offset.left + 'px', top: canvas_offset.top + 'px', height: canvas_height + 'px', width: canvas_width + 'px' });

    // Pass the data to the method for rendering of text over the pdf canvas.
    PDFJS.renderTextLayer({
        textContent: textContent,
        container: $("#text-layer").get(0),
        viewport: viewport,
        textDivs: []
    });
});
```

source: https://usefulangle.com/post/90/javascript-pdfjs-enable-text-layer

Comment: This answer is not helpful to this question, he wants hyperlinks, not text layers. You should use page.getAnnotations instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
 setupAnnotations = (page, viewport, canvas, annotationLayerDiv) => {
        let pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
        let pdfjsViewer = window['pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer'];

        //BELOW--------- Create Link Service using pdf viewer
        let pdfLinkService = new pdfjsViewer.PDFLinkService();

        page.getAnnotations().then(function (annotationsData) {
            viewport = viewport.clone({
                dontFlip: true
            });

            let pdf_canvas = canvas;
          
            // Render the annotation layer
            annotationLayerDiv.style.left = pdf_canvas.offsetLeft + 'px';
            annotationLayerDiv.style.top = pdf_canvas.offsetTop + 'px';
            annotationLayerDiv.style.height = viewport.height + 'px';
            annotationLayerDiv.style.width = viewport.width + 'px';

            pdfjsLib.AnnotationLayer.render({
                viewport: viewport,
                div: annotationLayerDiv,
                annotations: annotationsData,
                page: page,
                linkService: pdfLinkService,
                enableScripting: true,
                renderInteractiveForms: true
            });
    }
```

IMP ---- Do not forget to add this CSS

```
.annotation-layer{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
}

.annotation-layer section{
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.annotation-layer section a{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}
```

In above example, Link service instance is created using class in pdf viewer, which is being passed as parameter to annotation layer render method.
Please refer source code of [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) refer to /web/pdf_viewer.js - class PDFLinkService for more information.

PDF.js version - v2.9.359

Comment: Are you able to expand this newer example to include the scripts you're referencing in order to get the viewer and pdflinkservice references to work?

Comment: I can't use PDFLinkService, there's no such class in viewer.js, I've copied the pdf_link_service code from pdf.js github into my project, but it can't find and import "pdfjs-lib", I can't get it to work, can you PLEASE explain how to do it? :( I can't implement annotations and I really need it, I would appreciate it so much if you could explain how to do it now, since I think certain things have changed in pdf.js

Comment: @SMH I have not tried it with newer version of pdf.js and yes looks like some things are changed, though you can find pdf_link_service.js file inside web folder which you can try to use instead.

Comment: @PranjalKoshti Yeah I figured it out by asking it in pdf.js github, and they really don't want us to directly work with those files (pdf_link_service.js), so he told me to check out their example components and access pdfLinkService as they did, through the pdf_viewer.js, here's the link for example components https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/components I was following their `pageViewer.js` example, so you just add pdf_viewer.js through a script tag in your HTML file and then use it in your script, as the example file does