# Display annotations/hyperlinks using pdf.js

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, pdf.js

I've managed to display a sample PDF file using mozilla's pdf.js. On the 1st page of the PDF file there is one internal link to page 2 and one external link to google.com.

My next step is getting the links in the sample PDF to work (be clickable) and I'm struggling with this one.

At the moment all I can do is get the links/annotations and print them to the console. Can anyone help me render these links to the annotations div layer?

I've looked through the pdf.js docs but I can't quite find what I'm looking for... I'm just looking to add this clickable links feature to the simple code below.

Here is a code pen of my progress so far: http://codepen.io/laurencemeah/pen/ONrJXj

```js
var pdfFile = 'URL PATH TO PDF FILE';
var pageNum = 1;

PDFJS.getDocument(pdfFile).then(function(pdf) {

  pdf.getPage(pageNum).then(function(page) {
    var desiredWidth = document.getElementById('pdf-holder').getBoundingClientRect().width;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(1);
    var scale = desiredWidth / viewport.width;
    var scaledViewport = page.getViewport(scale);

    var canvas = document.getElementById('pdf-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = scaledViewport.height;
    canvas.width = scaledViewport.width;

    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: scaledViewport
    };

    page.render(renderContext);

    page.getAnnotations().then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      // now display them in annotation layer div
    });

  });

});
```

```css
#pdf-holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
```

```html
<script src="http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>

<div id="pdf-holder">
  <canvas id="pdf-canvas"></canvas>
  <div id="annotation-layer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/components ?

Comment: Hi, I did have a look at that but it seems very different to the code example I have at the moment. Normally that wouldn't be a problem but I have wrote zoom, next page and other functions  (not included in the code pen) that aren't really working with that components example. I actually found something close to what I'm looking for but I think it's using a much older version of PDF.js because i cant use some of the methods he uses - http://jsfiddle.net/seikichi/RuDvz/2/ I'm trying to re-create this without jQuery but to be honest I'm pretty new to JS so it's tuff.

Comment: Throw away code example you have and start using simpleviewer example -- it has all you need and will use official library (you have third-party out-of-date library in the jsfiddle).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Links, Hyperlinks into a canvas using PDF.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953879/links-hyperlinks-into-a-canvas-using-pdf-js)