# Generate a clickable pdf from html

Tags: javascript, pdf, vuejs3

**In Summary**:

I want to dynamically generate pdfs from html. I want the resultant pdf to be searchable/clickable - NOT an image. I would like a way to do this that is compatible with vue3.

**Background**:

I have a Vue3 project that returns long and wordy lists of results from an API.

On the site, the results are in accordions and look great.

I want to let my users download a PDF of the results. I would like to make a minimal template for the pdf that shows an expanded (no accordions) version of the result list.

As far as I can tell there are two basic ways to do this:

1. Create a print style in css and let users "save" the result to file as a pdf
2. use one of a number of "html2pdf" style modules to generate the pdf

Neither approach seems to really do what I want:

routing the user to a print result leads to differing behaviour on mobile and desktop and I can't figure out how to tell the browser to just offer a pdf download.

all the various "htmltpdf" type modules I have found so far have great options and defaults but they output the pdf as an image...

I want my users to be able to select and copy the contents of the pdf - there are phone numbers and links embedded for example.

Is there some way to do this in vue; A pleasant and nice-looking download experience AND a clickable/searchable pdf?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Links, Hyperlinks into a canvas using PDF.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953879/links-hyperlinks-into-a-canvas-using-pdf-js)

Comment: Not really. I don't want to render an existing pdf. I want to generate one from html. Ideally in a new tab with the browser's own pdfviewer. Or just download the pdf.

Comment: @KJ I'm experimenting with a "hidden" version of the content not in accordions to display during a print call. This seems to help standardize the look of the site. It means I am loading at least two full versions of the content though. Not sure if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use puppeteer to create pdf using html.

**Step 1:** Install puppeteer

```
npm i puppeteer
```

**Step 2:** Write a function to that renders your html into the browser and saves the page as pdf

```
async getPdfFromHtml(html: string): Promise<any> {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({ printBackground: true, format: 'A4' });
  await page.close();
  await browser.close();

  return pdfBuffer;
}
```

**Step 3:** Call this function wherever you want:

```
const html = 'your-html-template-string';

// here you will get the pdf buffer
const pdfBuffer = await getPdfFromHtml(html);
```

**Step 4:** Now you can send your pdf buffer to frontend. The following is an example of how I do in express.js

```
const buffer = pdfBuffer.toString('base64').replace(/([^\0]{76})/g, '$1\n') + '\n\n';

res.header('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
res.send(buffer);
```

**Step 5:** Now on frontend, all you need is call this api using an achor tag and the pdf will be downloaded.

**Optional:** Another alternative is to upload this buffer to aws-s3 and return the url to FE, the pdf will be downloaded once you redirect to that url.

Comment: So basically bypass code and pass my html directly to the browsers built-in print renderer?

Comment: Am I right in thinking puppeteer needs to install a full chromium client server-side for this to work?

Comment: If you want a quick solution without the interaction of backend, then use `window.print()`(this will have same behaviour as pressing cmd+P in browser) OR you can implement this puppeteer solution on FE and pass your html into the function.

But ideally, if I have a download button, then I would call an api on click and that api would return the pdf file which I would be able to download on FE.