PDF Links Not Clickable When Rendering with pdf.js
I'm using pdf.js to render a PDF file in the browser. The PDF contains clickable links, but after rendering the file, the links are no longer clickable. Here’s a simplified version of the code I’m using:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>View PDF</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.13.216/pdf.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .pdf-page {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 20px auto;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        .loader {
            border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
            animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        @keyframes spin {
            0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
            100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
        }

        #pdf-container {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="loader" id="loader"></div>
<div id="pdf-container"></div>

<script>
    var url = 'pdf-url.pdf';

    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.13.216/pdf.worker.min.js';

    var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
    loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
        var numPages = pdf.numPages;
        var loadedPages = 0;

        for (var i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
            pdf.getPage(i).then(function(page) {
                var scale = 1.5;
                var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });

                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.className = 'pdf-page';
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;

                document.getElementById('pdf-container').appendChild(canvas);

                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport: viewport
                };
                page.render(renderContext).promise.then(function() {
                    loadedPages++;
                    if (loadedPages === numPages) {
                        document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('pdf-container').style.display = 'block';
                    }
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.error('Error rendering page: ' + error);
                    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
                });
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error('Error getting page: ' + error);
                document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
            });
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error loading PDF: ' + error);
        document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
    });

    // Disable all keyboard inputs
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Disable right-click
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>

The PDF is rendering correctly, but all the clickable links in the document are no longer working. From my research, it seems that this might be an issue with how pdf.js handles annotations or links, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
How can I make the links in the PDF clickable while using pdf.js for rendering? Any help would be appreciated!

Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953879/links-hyperlinks-into-a-canvas-using-pdf-js ?
